# Volley library return html instead of JSON in android

Tags: android, api, android-studio, mobile, android-volley

I am building an android application where I am making a Login Page and implementing a simple POST web API. Previously it was working fine but suddenly it stops working and now it is always returning me HTML code. Below is my volley code

```
  params.put("username", username);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    params.put("deviceToken", device_token);
                    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(params);
                    Log.e("params ", obj.toString());
                    System.out.println("Login Details=="+obj.toString());
              getDataFromApi(obj.toString());



 private void getDataFromApi (String bodyParams) {

        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        final String requestBody = bodyParams;
        String url = Utility.getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext(), "apiUrl")+Constants.loginUrl;
        Log.e("URL", url);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    try {
                        Log.e("Result", result);
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);

                        String success = object.getString("status");
                        String message = object.getString("message");
                        System.out.println("message= "+message);
                        if (success.equals("200")) {

                            JSONObject data = object.getJSONObject("record");

                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.userId, object.getString("id"));
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "accessToken", object.getString("token"));

                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "schoolName", data.getString("sch_name"));
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.currency, data.getString("currency_symbol"));
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.loginType, data.getString("role"));
                            String dateFormat = data.getString("date_format");
                            dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("m", "MM");
                            dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("d", "dd");
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "dateFormat", dateFormat);
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "language", data.getString("language"));
                            String imgUrl = Utility.getSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext(), "imagesUrl") + data.getString("image");
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.userImage, imgUrl);
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.userName, data.getString("username"));
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "schoolName", data.getString("sch_name"));


                            if(data.getString("role").equals("parent")) {
                                JSONArray childArray = data.getJSONArray("parent_childs");
                                if(childArray.length() == 1) {

                                    Utility.setSharedPreferenceBoolean(getApplicationContext(), "isLoggegIn", true);

                                    Utility.setSharedPreferenceBoolean(getApplicationContext(), "hasMultipleChild", false);
                                    Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.studentId, childArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("student_id"));
                                    Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.classSection, childArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("class") + " - " + childArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("section"));
                                    Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "studentName", childArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));

                                    Intent asd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentDashboard.class);
                                    startActivity(asd);
                                    finish();
                                } else {

                                    Utility.setSharedPreferenceBoolean(getApplicationContext(), "hasMultipleChild", true);
                                    childNameList.clear(); childIdList.clear(); childImageList.clear();
                                    childClassList.clear(); childListAdapter.clear();
                                    for (int i = 0; i<childArray.length(); i++) {
                                        childNameList.add(childArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                                        childIdList.add(childArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("student_id"));
                                        childImageList.add(childArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
                                        childClassList.add(childArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("class") + " - "
                                                + childArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("section") );
                                        childListAdapter.add(childArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                                    }
                                    childListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    showChildList();
                                }

                                Log.e("CHILD ARRAY LENGTH", childArray.length()+"..");

                            } else if (data.getString("role").equals("student")) {

                                Utility.setSharedPreferenceBoolean(getApplicationContext(), "isLoggegIn", true);
                                Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.classSection, data.getString("class") + " (" + data.getString("section")+")");
                                Utility.setSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), Constants.studentId, data.getString("student_id"));
                                Intent asd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentDashboard.class);
                                startActivity(asd);
                                finish();

                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), object.getString("errorMsg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Utility.setSharedPreferenceBoolean(getApplicationContext(), "isLoggegIn", false);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.noInternetMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Log.e("Volley Error", volleyError.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, R.string.invalidPassword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                headers.put("Client-Service", "smartschool");
                headers.put("Auth-Key", "schoolAdmin@");
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }



            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }



            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                50000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

here is response retrieved from API

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#424242" />
            <title>Login : Your School Name</title>
            <link href="https://qdocs.tech/uploads/school_content/admin_small_logo/1.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://qdocs.tech/backend/usertemplate/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://qdocs.tech/backend/usertemplate/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://qdocs.tech/backend/usertemplate/assets/css/form-elements.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://qdocs.tech/backend/usertemplate/assets/css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://qdocs.tech/backend/usertemplate/assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
            <style type="text/css">
                body{background:linear-gradient(to right,#676767 0,#dadada 100%);}
                /*.loginbg {background: #455a64;}*/
                .top-content{position: relative;}
                .mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_dragger .mCSB_dragger_bar {
                    background: rgb(53, 170, 71);}
                .bgoffsetbgno{background: transparent; border-right:0 !important; box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29); border-radius: 4px;}
    
                .loginradius{border-radius: 4px;}
    
            </style>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <!-- Top content -->
            <div class="top-content">
    
                <div class="inner-bg">
    
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="">
    
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 nopadding bgoffsetbgno col-md-offset-4">
                                    <div class="loginbg loginradius login390">
                                        <div class="form-top">
                                            <div class="form-top-left logowidth">
                                                <img src="https://qdocs.tech/uploads/school_content/admin_logo/1.png" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-bottom">
                                            <h3 class="font-white">User Login</h3>
                                                                                                                            <form action="https://qdocs.tech/site/userlogin" method="post">
                                                <input type='hidden' name='ci_csrf_token' value=''/>                                            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">
                                                        Username</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" class="form-username form-control" id="email">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                                                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" class="form-password form-control" id="password">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                                                    <span class="text-danger"></span>
                                                </div>
```

> can anyone help me please and tell me which code I had written wrong.

Comment: Have you checked that you are getting string json response?

Comment: yes, response retrieve from api is in html

Comment: "Previously it was working fine but suddenly it stops working" - please explain what you did between it working and now. Also, do you own the API? What is the URL?

Comment: I have an old apk , API is working fine in that apk. this api is built by the same code a few years earlier. but now it is giving html response. I changed nothing in android code

Comment: i also facing same problem but no one cant answer properly